# How could Jenkins access to a website without security certificates?

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins, selenium-ide

I need to run a script which was made on Selenium IDE. This script runs on a test site. This site does not have a Security Certificate and when I enter into this website for the first time this screen appears:

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pisMs.png)

So I have to add the Security Certificate clicking on the "Añadir Excepcion" (Add exception) link. And this validation won't appear again.

But when I run the Selenium script on Jenkins this is the test suite result:

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4AAq.png)

I think this appears because Jenkins/Selenium Server.jar can't access the website because of certification validation. Can someone tell me if this is correct or incorrect, and if it is correct how could I "jump" or evade this validation.

> SOLUTION:
>
> Add the -trustAllSSLCertificates command in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium can only talk to the DOM in a displayed web page. The alert that shows up about the web page's certificate is made by the browser and is not part of the web page. If you can only use Selenium IDE and you can't use obvious workarounds (open the URL manually and tell the browser to accept it, then run the test), then you appear to be stuck.

If you're writing Selenium Webdriver calls in some other language like Java or Python, you could use a library called Sikuli to match and click icons on the screen. Let Sikuli detect the security alert and click the right things, then go back to Selenium Webdriver calls to poke the web site.

Answer (score 0):

There are workarounds available.
https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-totw-https-and-self-signed-certificate-exceptions

> The workaround for this problem is to create your own Firefox profile,
>   with the specific certificate added on it by hand, and then tell
>   Selenium to launch the browser based on that profile.
>
> Another interesting approach - the one we take at Sauce Labs, where we
>   can’t do this kind of trick, because we just don’t know which
>   certificate the user will need before the test starts - is to use the
>   RCE (Remember Certificate Exception). This is a plugin that will
>   automatically detect the warning and make the browser go through it,
>   returning control to Selenium after 4 or 5 seconds. Notice that if you
>   use this approach, you will need to make sure your tests will tolerate
>   this five-second additional delay before opening the page.